# Check if react element is empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't want to render the title when description is empty

```
var description = <MyElement />; // render will return nothing in render in some cases

if (!description) { // this will not work because its an object (reactelement)
    return null;
}

<div>
     {title}
     {description}
</div>
```

Whats the correct way instead of !description to check if its empty?

Comment: Do you have any state/props that you can check to see whether description _should_ be empty? It is better to do the check using these, rather than inspecting an element's children.

Comment: No not really the data is build by some props which are converted/filtered  in the myelement component. If there is no way I need to move this Logik to the parent component. Then I could check in this props.

Answer (score 3):

```
var description, title;

if (this.props.description) {
    description = <Description description={this.props.description} />;

    if (this.props.title) {
      title = <Title title={this.props.title} />;
    }
}

<div>
     {title}
     {description}
</div>
```

Or:

```
render() {
  const { description, title } = this.props;

  return (
    <div>
       {title && description && <Title title={title} />}
       {description && <Description description={description} />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Imo it's better practice that if your description element isn't needed then it isn't rendered, rather than returning null in it's render. Since you would likely be sending the data through a prop. And likewise if you don't want to render this component at all, then that should happen in the parent.

Comment: So the only solution is to move the logic of data conversion/filters in the element into the parent and check then on this vars?

Comment: Yup; as I understand it this is very deliberately part of React's top-down rendering scheme.